# Annaprasana timing

Tags: rituals, samskara

- Greetings. I have a doubt regarding the Annaparasan timings. We know the fact that "For a son, this is done in even months - the 6th, 8th, 10th or 12th months. For a daughter this is done in odd months - 5th, 7th or 9th months."

Here comes my doubt. When do we say 6th month- - what is the definition of 6th month? Is that mean when 5 months over and the 6th month starts OR the 6th month over and 7th-month starts?